# Make a Qt window autofit to the screen's size

Tags: qt, user-interface, mobile, screen

I have a Qt application which needs to be loaded on mobile devices of different screen sizes. How do I make it autofit to the mobile device's screen size?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you not want [fullScreen](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qwidget.html#fullScreen-prop) but rather windowed and matching the screen size?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want your application's main window to occupy the whole screen as soon as it starts, use [`QWidget::showMaximized`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#showMaximized), e.g.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyMainWidget widget;
    widget.showMaximized();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Note that `showMaximized` is a convenience function which internally calls the `QWidget::setWindowState` mentioned by Andrew:

```
void QWidget::showMaximized()
{
    // ...
    setWindowState((windowState() & ~(Qt::WindowMinimized | Qt::WindowFullScreen))
                   | Qt::WindowMaximized);
    show();
}
```

Comment: Let's say my application's main window's size is 240x320 pixels. Then I had to load it on a mobile device with 160X160 screen size. Will it auto-resize to the available screen size using showMaximized? Thanks...

Comment: i try it but it didnt fit the window to my mobile screen ?

Answer (score 6):

If you really want the geometry, you could use [`QDesktopWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html) to get information about the display, including the geometry of it.

If you just want the window to be sized properly, however, you should use [`QWidget::setWindowState`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setWindowState), as [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689453/make-a-qt-window-autofit-to-the-screens-size/4691527#4691527) suggested.

Answer (score 3):

`void QWidget::setWindowState ( Qt::WindowStates windowState )`

Sets the window state to windowState. The window state is a OR'ed combination of Qt::WindowState: Qt::WindowMinimized, Qt::WindowMaximized, Qt::WindowFullScreen, and Qt::WindowActive.

From documentation of QWidget. Hope it will help